# how can I make the fb-login-button parent clickable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've put the fb-login-button inside a wrapper element with the same height and background so that I can make it appear to be wider than facebook allows it to be (max 400px).

This works well for the most part but I need to be able to click the wrapper to login with facebook. Is this possible? And if so how might i go about doing this?

my html:

```
  <div class="fb-login-button-wrapper">
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-width="100%"></div>
  </div>
```

however whats actually rendered is an iframe and i believe the clickable element is somewhere in there.

Comment: why do you need this? you should either use the login button (including its controls) or your own button with FB.login.

Comment: because you need facebooks button if you want (which I do) to display the users friends who use the app and facebooks button has restrictions on its width that cannot be overridden. I need the button to be bigger because thats what looks best at a certain screen size.

Comment: Since the markup for the button is replaced by an iframe, you have no direct JavaScript access to it from your domain. And I would advise against any attempts to even try and get this to work using any kind of trickery - because there's a good chance Facebook will detect that as some kind of fraudulent click-jacking attempt. Besides, you are not allowed to modify any of their social plugins apart from the options they specifically offer for that.